# How to flatten a list of lists with a known separator in a single operation

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list with a known separator `;`. How would I flatten that list if it ever contains a string separated by that separator? For example:

```
>>> [item for item in [1,2,'2;3']]
[1, 2, '2;3']
```

I can do this verbosely with a second for loop:

```
vals = []
separator = ';'
for _val in [1,2,'2;3']:
    _val = str(_val)
    if separator not in _val: 
        vals.append(_val)
    else:
        vals.extend(_val.split(separator))
```

Is there a way to do this in a single operation, such as with a list comprehension or `chain` ?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do a second list comprehension with the result, but hoping to use `chain` or a single one.

Comment: So give a [mcve] and explain the specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the final values to all be stings, you can call split on all of them after converting to string and use`itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
import itertools
c = itertools.chain.from_iterable(str(item).split(";") for item in [1,2,'2;3'])
print(list(c))
```

result:

```
['1', '2', '2', '3']
```

Comment: perfect, yes this is what I was looking for. Thanks for explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension *(delete int type cast if you don't need items to be int)*:

```
test = [1, 2, "3;4", 5]
res = [int(item) for items in test for item in str(items).split(";")]
print(res)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: this is a list comprehension, not a for-loop *statement*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks. I've edited my response.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a generator if you want all values to be int:

```
def values(items):
    for x in items:
        if isinstance(x, str) and separator in x:
            yield from map(int, x.split(separator))
        yield x

separator = ';'    
vals = list(values([ 1, 2, '2;3' ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be achieved without imports using a nested list comprehension:

```
sep = ';'
a = [item for sublist in [str(i).split(sep) for i in lst] for item in sublist]
```

outputs:

`['1', '2', '2', '3']`